# Delete selected value from array in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have an array `entertainment` that contains several values, e.g. `favorite bands: ["coldplay", "u2", "oscar and the wolf", "indiana"]`

I created a view that shows each value in a seperate container and I want to be able to delete a value by clicking a link in the container. I have been able to delete values, however it is always the first value in the array that is deleted.

I'm stuck on passing the selected value to the method in the controller. So when I select the link in the container for `indiana` I want the value (or actually all values) `indiana` to be deleted from the array.

**the view**

```
<div class="interest-container">
  <% @user.profile.entertainment.each do |interest| %>
    <span class="interest-selected"><%= "#{interest.downcase}" %>
        <%= link_to "delete", @interest, :method => 'delete',
                           data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
    </span>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**the destroy method in the controller**

```
  def destroy
    @user = User.find_by(params[:id])
    @profile = @user.profile
    @profile.entertainment.delete_at(params[@interest].to_i) 
    @profile.save
    redirect_to profile_path(current_user, tab:"entertainment")
  end
```

I understand that `delete_at` is used for deleting a value at a specific position in the array (`delete_at(3)` would delete `oscar and the wolf`) and I should use something like `delete('oscar and the wolf')`, however whatever I've tried, I have not been able to pass the selected value to the method.

Comment: Could you please let us know what value your  '@interest' has?

Comment: you are not using the block variable name i.e `interest` instead you are using `@interest`. where did you define `@interest`?

Comment: It has no value (as far as I know), I've just been trying to pass the `selected interest` from the view to the `destroy method` in the `controller`.

Comment: could you please let us know the controller name, is it interests_controller?

Comment: The name of the `controller` is `ProfilesController`.

Comment: please can you show your params, I am a bit confuse if it is profiles_controller delete method then how you can redirect to 'delete' action with @interest which has no value.

Comment: @GauravGupta forget about the `params` and the `@interest`. As mentioned, I'm able to delete a specific value by using e.g. `@profile.entertainment.delete('coldplay')` from the array. All I need to do is replace `'coldplay'` with the selected value in the view.  I've just been trying a lot of things and am stuck.

Comment: you can do it with 'each_with_index' and pass 'index' value to your delete action and delete array element  as  @profile.entertainment.delete(params[:index])

Comment: ok, but how do I pass the value? Should I just replace the `@interest` with `index`?

Comment: As you said that destroy method is in profiles_controller then you can do it like: <%= link_to 'delete', profile_path(@user.profile, index: index), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }%>, so at destroy action you will get 'params[:index]'

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 
@profile.entertainment.delete_at(params[@interest].to_i)

you should write :
**@profile.entertainment.delete("#{params[:interest]}")**

If the value which is to be deleted is coming with params[:interest].

Answer (score 0):

is the route for delete interest

```
   DELETE /interests/:id(.:format)         interests#destroy
```

update views code

```
<div class="interest-container">
  <% @user.profile.entertainment.each do |interest| %>
    <span class="interest-selected"><%= "#{interest.downcase}" %>
        <%= link_to "delete", interest, :method => 'delete',
                           data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
    </span>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

create interests controller and add destroy action as

```
def destroy
    @profile = current_user.profile
    entertainment = @profile.entertainment.find(params[:id]) 
    entertainment.destroy unless entertainment.nil? 
    redirect_to profile_path(current_user, tab:"entertainment")
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing the line:

```
@profile.entertainment.delete_at(params[@interest].to_i)
```

in the `ProfilesController` to:

```
@profile.entertainment.delete(params[:id])
```

Answer (score -1):

It seem like you forgot to set your `@interest` var.